# What will be with the code stays after "await" promise what will never resolve?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have a method what is called often and have few "await" parts and piece of code after them, but sometimes this promises can be unresolved at all, so the part of code after "awaits" will never be called. So I am wondering what happens with this part of code?
Will it litter the memory and after often calls of this method site will start to lagging?

Here is an example of my code:

```js
    class Test {
        constructor() {
            this.runTest();
        }
    
        playAnimation() {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                this.timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log('Anim completed.');
    
                    resolve();
                }, 3000);
            });
        }
    
        stopAnimation = () => {
            document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.stopAnimation);
    
            clearTimeout(this.timeOut);
        };
    
        async method() {
            await this.playAnimation();

            // If click twice, This loop will never execute, as promise never resolve.
            for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                //Something
            }
    
            console.log('Promise resolve');
        }
    
        runTest = () => {
            document.body.removeEventListener('click', this.runTest);
    
            document.body.addEventListener('click', this.stopAnimation);
    
            document.body.addEventListener('click', this.runTest);
    
            this.method();
        };
    }
    
    new Test();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering what happens with this part of code? Will it litter the memory?

No. It just doesn't get called, and will get garbage-collected like any other object. Notice the `async` function essentially forms a closure over a `.then()` callback installed on the `await`ed promise - as long as that promise is referenced and could still be resolved, so are its handlers, the suspended execution of the `async` function, and the promise it had returned.

However, notice that it is not exactly a best practice to keep promises unresolved forever - it does not give code that was waiting for them the ability to clean up resources. A better approach would be to `reject()` the promise when you are clearing the timer from `stopAnimation`, and have your `method` handle being stopped one way or another.